# Values of a quadratic polynomial with restricted prime factors

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $a,c$ be non-zero, co-prime square-free integers. Let $P_a$ be the set of primes such that the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = 1$ and define $P_c$ likewise. Consider the quadratic polynomial $x^2 - ac$. How long does one count the set

$$\displaystyle S_{a,c}(B) = \{ x \in \mathbb{N}: x < B, p | x^2 - ac \Rightarrow p \in P_a \cap P_c\}?$$

Note that if $Q_a, Q_c$ denote the complement in the primes of $P_a, P_c$ respectively then for $p \nmid ac$, $p | x^2 - ac$ means that $p \in P_a \cap P_c$ or $p \in Q_a \cap Q_c$.